# how to ensure async functions to be completed before certain point. Node JS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have these 3 mssql stored procedure executions that get array of data each and each of them is pushed to variable storedresults.

However, at the end of the day, only first and last execution will be completed and middle execution will be completed after root function is completed and therefore array value for middle execution will not be pushed.

```
function merchantGetSetting(inputData, callback) {


storedgetSettingProcedure.exec(function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        winston.info("ERROR WITH EXECUTING GET SETTING STORED PROCEDURE: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    else {
        winston.log('info', "SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED GET SETTING STORED PROCEDURE");
        storedresults.push([results]);

        }
    });

storedgetIntegrationProcedure.exec(function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        winston.info("ERROR WITH EXECUTING GET SETTING STORED PROCEDURE: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    else {
        winston.log('info', "SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED GET INTEGRATION STORED PROCEDURE");
        storedresults.push([results]);
    }
});


storedgetAccoutListProcedure.exec(function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        winston.info("ERROR WITH EXECUTING GET SETTING STORED PROCEDURE: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    else {

            winston.log('info', "SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED GET MERCHANT LIST STORED PROCEDURE");
            storedresults.push([results]);
            callback(null, storedresults)
    }
});
```

I do know a way to around this(sync call) but I would like to know more elegant way and hope for a simple fix for it.

Comment: Why not just execute all three SP calls in parallel and then push the results after they're all completed?

Comment: I haven't learn async library yet. I'll try it and see how it goes. thanks

Comment: I find: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I knew only middle store procedure execution was completed too late, I used process.nextTick on that function and moved callback to app.js from last function to middle one like this.

```
 process.nextTick(function() { 
storedgetIntegrationProcedure.exec(function(error, results) {
if (error) {
    winston.info("ERROR WITH EXECUTING GET SETTING STORED PROCEDURE: " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
else {
    winston.log('info', "SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED GET INTEGRATION STORED PROCEDURE");
    storedresults.push([results]);
callback(null, storedresults)
}
});
}
```

this process.nextTick ensured middle function to be completed last and I was able to get data I wanted.

I am still open for more suggestion but this was simplest solution I figured.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) ?

it has quite a few functions to achieve this in different ways.

look at the `.parallel`